# How to take screenshot while popping the error message using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

I'm new to Selenium. I need to know how to take the screenshot while popping up the error message.
I've browsed in web and used the below codes which is not satisfying my requirements

```
File src=screenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(src, new File("D:\\"+result.getName()+".png"));
```

The above code is not capturing the pop-up msg. It is just capturing the behind screen only.

```
BufferedImage image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(tk.getScreenSize()));
ImageIO.write(image, "JPG", new File("D:\\"+formatter.format(now.getTime())+".jpg"));
```

Robo screenshot is not working when I switched to some other screen. SO when the error occurs it is just capturing the present screen.

Someone please give me the code snippet?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Use TakesScreenshot interface to take the screenshot.